# HTML table from 2D JSON arrays without keys

Tags: html, json, html-table

I am facing problem in creating a table from a JSON array which don't have any keys. Following is the JSON array. It is saved as file "data.json"

```
[["Vishnu", 25],["Joginder", 22],["Amar", 27],["Rohan", 24],["Karan", 23]].
```

I don't want the player names, but I want the second entry which is their age to make a table like

> **Player No.** **Age**
>
> 5 25
>
> 7  22
>
> 3 27
>
> 1 24
>
> 8 23

I made the following code, but there is some problem. It is not working, can anyone suggest me

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Player Record Data</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        table
        {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table th
        {
            background-color: #F7F7F7;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        table th, table td
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Generate Table For Player Records" onclick="GenerateTable()" />

    <div id="dvTable">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function GenerateTable()
        {                           
            d3.json('data.json', function (e,data){
            //Build an array containing Player records.
            var player = new Array();
            player.push(["Player Id", "Player Name", "Player Age"]);
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
               {
               var item = data[i];
               var name = item[0];
               var age = item[1];
               player.push([i, name, age]);
               }
            //Create a HTML Table element.
           var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
           table.border = "1";

            //Get the count of columns.
            var columnCount = player[0].length;

            //Add the header row.
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
               var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
               headerCell.innerHTML = player[0][i];
               row.appendChild(headerCell);
           }

         //Add the data rows.
           for (var i = 1; i < player.length; i++) {
                row = table.insertRow(-1);
           for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
               var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                  cell.innerHTML = player[i][j];
              }
         }    
            var dvTable = d cument.getElementById("dvTable");
            dvTable.innerHTML = "";
            dvTable.appendChild(table);             
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
 var json = [["Vishnu", 25],["Joginder", 22],["Amar", 27],["Rohan", 24],["Karan", 23]]
document.write('<table>');
    for(i=0; i< json.length; i++){
      document.write('<tr><td>' + json[i][1] + '</td></tr>'); //prints the age on console
    }
document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: I don't want console, as it just prints to the screen. I want to display it in a web browser.

Comment: Thank you Ashfaq, but I already know this method. I want to call the data from another webpage or file using d3.json and make the table, which being asynchronous don't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample to get value from json array with indexes.

```
 <script>
    var data = [["Vishnu", 25], ["Joginder", 22], ["Amar", 27], ["Rohan", 24], ["Karan", 23]];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var playername = item[0];
        var age = item[1];
        //write table logic here

    }
</script>
```

Comment: whare is the issue you are facing in ??

Comment: Please check the question, it is edited now. I have provided my code here.

Comment: call method like onclick="javascript:GenerateTable();"  instead of onclick="GenerateTable();"

Answer (score 0):

Use below working sample to add table.

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Generate Table For Player Records" onclick="javascript:GenerateTable();" />
    <div id="dvTable">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function GenerateTable() {
           $('#dvTable').html('');
            var content = "<table>"
            content += '<tr><th>Player Id</th><th>Player Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>'
            var data = [["Vishnu", 25], ["Joginder", 22], ["Amar", 27], ["Rohan", 24], ["Karan", 23]];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var item = data[i];
                var id = i + 1;
                var playername = item[0];
                var age = item[1];
                //write table logic here
                content += '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + playername + '</td><td>' + age + '</td></tr>';
            }


            content += "</table>"

            $('#dvTable').append(content);
        }


    </script>
</body>
```